# How can I get the events for a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the latest version (2.12) of the Facebook API I'm trying to get (public) events for a page, using the Graph API Explorer.

However, I can't seem to get it working:

[image]

When I hover over the greyed out "id" or "name" on the left, it says "Field is empty or disallowed by the access token".

Now the page I'm using as an exmple here is Techcrunch, and they have plenty of events coming up. So "empty" doesn't seem to be the issue.

On the "disallowed" side I've checked the API reference on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/events/.

However, I can't seem to find any issue here either. It says "Reading Page events requires a valid Page access token or User access token with basic permissions.".

What am I missing here? Any hints are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visit https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#pages-4-4

Currently Facebook is not returning events for pages using Pages API unless you use an user accesss token and that user has been invited to any of the  events of the page or is attending/interested in any of the events of the page.

Comment: ok, that sounds like an explanation. However, I don't see where it says that. Is that the correct link? Maybe I'm blind?

Comment: Just to confirm: I've tried using the user access token after attending an event (clicking "Interested") - that works.

Comment: For me it’s also not 100% clear at this time but it seems that now to access to a Pages API endpoint, such as ‘/page/events’,  you need a page permission such as manage_pages (which requires that the owner of the page gives the permission to your app) to access that page events. In the text they say that all new apps must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the API. If your app doesn’t have any Pages API permission approved it’ll must go to review after the review resumed. This changes were very sudden so we need to wait for the next days to see how the situation will develop :|

Comment: currently to access events you can also use a user endpoint such as ‘/me/events’ or ‘/me/events/not-replied’ using an access token valid for that user. you can get the events that the user was invited to or is going/interested

Comment: Thanks, that’s very helpful. Let’s hope this’ll get resolved soon!

Comment: Thank you Zuckerberg for messing up my website!

Comment: See my last post.

Comment: @unknown_b I don't understand why, as the admin of a page, I can't just get some sort of token (specific to the one page) for my server-side app to read info about that page (like events and posts). Then the only security concern is leaking that server-side token, but this is pretty standard with lots of APIs. Is there really no way to do this right now? You HAVE to have a use login and grant access to manage_pages?

Answer (score 6):

I'm trying to do the same thing: getting public events from a page. Related to the above suggestions:

- I tried the short-lived user access token two weeks ago, which worked for a short time. Now it does not anymore. Does it for any of you?
- Both the long-lived user token, a page token generated with either a short- or long-lived user token do also not return any events.

At https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/#platforms, Facebook states:

> Beginning April 4, 2018, all apps, including those formerly approved, **must undergo App Review in order to gain access to the Events API**, Groups API, and Pages API. Apps accessing the Events API and Groups API will lose access and require review once App Review resumes.

So being reviewed might help. I will report further.

**Update 1**: an answer on [this related bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/185630995395938/) reports states it  more clearly:

> App review required to use the following edges: GET /page/events and GET /me/events

Meanwhile they cancelled all pending review requests for the Graph API 3.0 changes, so I have to resubmit.

**Update 2**: My project got rejected & I'm not bothering to continue it now.

Comment: We had resubmitted but just cancelled or pending for approval since many weeks. they not communicate, nor proper answer for approval. Horrible experienced with facebook event api

Comment: Hey @TejasTank, I got rejected once in app review and gave up. Did you have any success so far?

Comment: No Yet, we don't got approval, they even not rejecting request. Its means facebook not actively working on approval process. Even 2 other my account I done same but yet not communication from facebook side.

Answer (score 5):

As unknow_b said :

> currently to access events you can also use a user endpoint such as ‘/me/events’ or ‘/me/events/not-replied’ using an access token valid for that user. you can get the events that the user was invited to or is going/interested

But the access token user, is only working for 1 hour !
Does someone have another better idea?

Comment: This is probably not all that helpful, but as I am looking to get PUBLIC events in my case, I’m currently looking into getting the events with Scrapy. Far from ideal, but a workaround until FB fix their API.

Comment: I'm looking to get PUBLIC events too. What's Scrapy and how to use it?

Comment: regarding this, you can get long lived tokens & refresh the access tokens. read [[https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing/#generate-long-lived-token]]

Comment: Just a quick update here: I have looked into Scrapy to get public events from Facebook. Unfortunately, however, this is more complicated than I had hoped. The main reason for this is that Facebooks loads much of the content on an event page via JavaScript. As a result, the content is only loaded after Scrapy "sees" the page. Now there are ways to tackle this (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550114/can-scrapy-be-used-to-scrape-dynamic-content-from-websites-that-are-using-ajax), but this seems to be too much work for me at this stage.

Comment: I thought the same thing about long lived tokens. They have disabled these too as it pertains to the graph api and business page data.

Answer (score 5):

### 2023-02 update - Official Events API

#### TL;DR

You can use the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to easily test access

- Generate a user or page token
- and use this URL : [page_name_or_id]/events

Here is a screenshot with and example [image]

#### Long version

The API for page events is called the "Official Events API". Some public documentation is available there : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/official-events but unfortunately the official reference access seems to be locked and only available for partners (it should be available [there](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/official-event) and FB seems to have frozen detailed access, they have a page with a [form mentioning it](https://developers.facebook.com/products/official-events-api/) was frozen with COVID).

*Note that "events" are also used to designate "user events", "analytic events" (for facebook analytics) so it's often hard to find the correct articles but "Official events" seem to be the term to designate page events.*

Managing page events can be done via a Facebook "business" Application (when you create a FB app you now have several choices of type), which you can/should connect to a Meta business account. From your meta business account, you can grant access to assets to system users such as your facebook page, and generate a "system user access token" that you can use in your code.

Some API calls on the official events endpoint are working, I have tested them using Postman with a system user token: something you can generate from your meta business interface

This mess is all the more complicated that you now have "classic pages" and "New Page experience" ([reference](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/2752670058165459?id=418112142508425)).

Comment: Cyril, yours is the most thorough answer I have found yet and I've scoured the documentation, Facebook developer community, and Stack Overflow. Thank you! Were you able to create an event for a page managed by a business account using the official_events endpoint? Any idea why they're still blaming COVID? (Sigh.)

Comment: Unfortunately no, I'm running into permission errors when using app or page access tokens, I have somewhat abandoned the topic

Comment: Not working in 10.2023

Answer (score 3):

Yep. Facebook has taken down the Graph API for page access tokens. I had this code in production for 2 years and it worked great. The only way to retrieve data (or was a week or so ago), was a temporary user token that lasts about 2 hours. It's totally broken my band's schedule page. I've been through every avenue and even spoke with a facebook ad team employee on the phone that was aware of it. She seemed to empathize but had no solution for me. I would count on it being down for a while.

Comment: The worst thing is that it’s hard to see how limiting access to public pages has any bearing on security issues. My feeling is that Facebook is seizing the moment to turn off that API feature because they see it as threatening to Facebook Local, their new local events app.

Comment: Exactly. Page access tokens that displayed page data of a business page associated to it, did not even ask for the viewer's data. I'm not sure why facebook thought it necessary to discontinue this service.

Answer (score 3):

I just created a python script, you can [see here](https://github.com/DaWe35/Facebook-event-crawler). It queries the given facebook page and it's events, and puts the data into a mysql table.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it won't be working anymore due to the scandal with Facebook Analytics (see [Why does Facebook Graph API say my account is non-active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49417886/why-does-facebook-graph-api-say-my-account-is-non-active)).

In the popular plugin `facebook-events-by-location-core`, you can take a look into the [issue#29](https://github.com/tobilg/facebook-events-by-location-core/issues/29) discussion. It's well explained there, and I don't think so there's a way we'll get the data in a public API available anymore.

There were also some rumours it was a competition for their (dead?) [Facebook Local](https://www.facebook.com/local/) app, but not sure about this.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally figured out a work around for this. On your fb application, you have to disable the secret key requirement. This can be found under the advance settings of your fb application console. It's called " Require App Secret".

Once you generate a fb PAGE access token, you get a fb page token, and then extend it. here is the token debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

You can extend the access token programmatically as explained here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

AND

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens

OR

There is also an extend tool in the access token debugger (just click on the debug and the extend button is bottom left): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

Comment: Hmm, my app has never required an app secret, still doesn't work.

Comment: hmmm .. this answer is specifically for pulling fb from a biz page with an extended life  access token using graph api.

Comment: An extended page token lasts indefinitely but I think it can still be revoked, like if the user that granted it changes their password or some other security issue like a few weeks ago when Facebook found a security leak and logged everyone out. At least I am pretty sure I've seen a debug message in my app before when working with the API, something like "this token was revoked because the user changed their password". Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Personally, I'm trying to use a page token to get data like events and videos off my page onto my website. I do use an extended page token, but I have an unlisted URL on my site which has a Facebook login, which then extends it and gets the page token and then caches it. That way, if the token ever gets revoked while the app is live I can just visit that URL and log in again. If the user isn't authorized for my particular page, like if some random person visits that URL, it just throws away the login. That might be overkill *shrug*

Answer (score -3):

Yes , we had a working product back in 2016 ( almost like it's successor Fb Local ) . We were monetised and ready and selling events tickets on the messenger chatbot. 
Idea was to solve discovery + booking for hyperlocal events. We went out of business and now its a heart ache to see Fb local.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O05PB.jpg)

Comment: Details for our product/business  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/did-we-get-killed-copied-facebook-yoparty-amrit-singh